# Generate an interpolated string n times so I get n different answers

Tags: r

I am trying to create dummy data from a list of options:

```
library('stringr')
#Generate a load of strings
line <- list(x1 = 10, x2 = 30,x3="There is no intestinal metaplasia, dysplasia or malignancy",x4="No Helicobacter are seen",x5="There is some ulceration",x6="There is no intercellular oedema in the surface epithelium",x7="PASstaining shows occasional spores, consistent with candida",x8="No herpetic viral inclusions are seen",x9="There is no dysplasia and no invasive carcinoma",x10="There is mild regenerative epithelial change, but neither dysplasia nor malignancy is seen",x11="The appearances are consistent with the endoscopic diagnosis of Barrett's oesophagus with active chronic inflammation",x12="The biopsies of oesophageal squamous mucosa show surface erosion and active chronic inflammation",x13="Numerous Candida spores and hyphae are present admixed with ulcer slough",x14="There is reactive basal cell hyperplasia and mild inflammatory epithelial atypia",x15="There is no significant increase in intraepithelialeosinophils",x16="No granulomas or viral inclusions are seen",x17="The appearances are those of Candida oesophagitis",x18="Neither dysplasia nor malignancy is seen",x19="The appearances are consistent with, but not specific for Barrett's (columnar lined) oesophagus")
listofResults<-unlist(sample(line,2,replace=T))
list.of.samples <- replicate(1000, paste(sample(1:10,1), "specimens collected the largest measuring", sample(1:5,1) ,"x", sample(1:5,1) ,"x", sample(1:5,1), "mm and the smallest", sample(1:5,1) ,"x", sample(1:5,1) ,"x", sample(1:5,1), "mm"), simplify=FALSE)
```

I want to then create 10 samples of the data. If I run:

```
#Merge the strings together randomly
histop<-paste (sample(list.of.samples,1,replace=T),str_c(sample(line,sample(3:10,1),replace=T),collapse='.'))
```

Then I get the randomly constructed string just fine, and as expected it changes every time I run it. However running

```
rep(histop,10)
```

Just results in the same result 10 times. So I tried to rep it as a function

```
histop<-function(){
  paste (sample(list.of.samples,1,replace=T),str_c(sample(line,sample(3:10,1),replace=T),collapse='.'))   
}
rep(histop(),10)
```

but I get the same result. How can I get 10 different strings?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. I just need to use replicate instead of rep. Ill need to read about this but I think replicate actually runs the line whereas, rep runs it once and then copies the result.

```
replicate(20,paste (sample(list.of.samples,1,replace=T),str_c(sample(line,sample(3:10,1),replace=T),collapse='.')))
```